# ValueError: shapes (399,1) and (2,) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I'm trying to build and run a Multiple Regression model using the Communities in the US dataset. However, I'm not sure why I'm getting this error even though the shapes of my X and Y variables are the same.

**My code:**

```
X1 = crime["pctWPubAsst"].values
y1 = crime["ViolentCrimesPerPop"].values

# Reshaping our variables 

X1 = X1.reshape(-1,1)
y1 = y1.reshape(-1,1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X1, y1, test_size=0.2, random_state=40)

linreg = LinearRegression()

linreg.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = linreg.predict(X_test)

print("R2: {}".format(regr.score(X_test, y_test)))
rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
print("Root Mean Squared Error: {}".format(rmse))

plt.scatter(X1, y1)
plt.plot(X_test, y_pred, color="black", linewidth=3)
plt.show()
```

**The Error I'm getting:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-77bd9073c3bd> in <module>
     15 y_pred = linreg.predict(X_test)
     16 
---> 17 print("R2: {}".format(regr.score(X_test, y_test)))
     18 rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
     19 print("Root Mean Squared Error: {}".format(rmse))

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in score(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    406         from .metrics import r2_score
    407         from .metrics.regression import _check_reg_targets
--> 408         y_pred = self.predict(X)
    409         # XXX: Remove the check in 0.23
    410         y_type, _, _, _ = _check_reg_targets(y, y_pred, None)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py in predict(self, X)
    219             Returns predicted values.
    220         """
--> 221         return self._decision_function(X)
    222 
    223     _preprocess_data = staticmethod(_preprocess_data)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py in _decision_function(self, X)
    204         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
    205         return safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,
--> 206                                dense_output=True) + self.intercept_
    207 
    208     def predict(self, X):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py in safe_sparse_dot(a, b, dense_output)
    140         return ret
    141     else:
--> 142         return np.dot(a, b)
    143 
    144 

<__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (399,1) and (2,) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

**Shape of my variables**

X_test = (399, 1)
y_test = (399, 1)

X_train = (1595, 1)
y_train = (1595, 1)

X1 = (1994, 1)
y1 = (1994, 1)

Thanks, appreciate the help.

Comment: you have a typo, it should be ```linreg.score``` instead of ```regr.score```

Comment: @StupidWolf sigh, not sure how I missed that - thanks a lot!